# clear the drawn bitmap with tranparent color on canvas in surfaceview in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

Hi I have a surfaceview in my layout, which i draw a bitmap. I make the surfaceview transparent by calling this code :

```
     SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
            holder.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT); 
// mBitmap is bitmap
mBitmap = mBitmap
```

Now i want to clear the screen by using this :

```
mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But it does not work.

I have tried the following also

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            this.mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The above things are not working.But it does not work. If i replace Color.TRANSPARENT with any other color it does paint the whole surface with that color i.e.

```
 mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.BlUE);
```

Please help me if anyone knows the answer.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you want to destroy your bitmap or clear it is contents?

Comment: I wanna clear the bitmap